# c# make a connection between a windows service and a c# project

Tags: c#

I have a c# project that prints or take some values from the keyboard to a console application. Can someone tell me how could I start this **application from a windows service**? I mean..when the computer is turned on I would like to pop up on my desktop the console application in which i can write values and see the result? Need some help. Please print a little code if you have one. Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just put the shortcut of the application in the Startup folder and it'll work. This is the simplest way, no code change needed

Comment: what do you mean? i add the exe file in the start() method from the windows service?

Comment: No. You add shortcut to exe file into user's Startup folder. Just Windows regular user Startup folder

Comment: i don't understand:). i want to make the conection programatically. I have the windows service. what should o add on onstart() method? don't i have to somehow create a client server connection?

Comment: You said that you want program start when the computer is turned on. This does not require windows service, you can do as i adviced or as Lloyd did. But if you want to use Windows Service anyways, you can use [Process.Start() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) there're examples on that link

Comment: i did specify i want the application to run based on the windows service. i said i would also like to monitor the application based on the windows service.:

Comment: i know how process.start works. what exe should i add in the Windows service methods?:) the application that i would like to run has a gui interface.

Comment: Sorry, you are mixing terms very much. There's no term like adding exe to service methods. Windows service cannot have its own gui interface. One thing you can do is Use ProcessInfo to start other gui application - that you've got already somewhere

Answer (score 3):

Windows Services usually run non-interactive under a specific system account rather than a desktop user account.

If you want the program to start when a user logs on you can always put a registry key in:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Run

And it will start when a user logs on.

Comment: how can i do that? i would like to do everything programatically. can you please guide me? what should i ad in the onstart (string []rags) method? the exe file that runs the application which read and writes to and from a console application?